# R: ranking numerical data in a data.frame

Tags: r, ranking

```
mydata <- data.frame(Train = c(14.2, 2.2, 11.9), Test = c(10, 11.2, 12))
rownames(mydata) <- c("Method1", "Method2", "Method3")
> mydata
        Train Test
Method1  14.2 10.0
Method2   2.2 11.2
Method3  11.9 12.0
```

I want to rank my `Train` and `Test` data as follows:

```
> mydata
        Train Test Train_rank Test_rank
Method1  14.2 10.0          3         1
Method2   2.2 11.2          1         2
Method3  11.9 12.0          2         3
```

I've tried the following:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata, .(stat), transform,
      Train_rank = rank(Train),
      Test_rank = rank(Test),
)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`, we can use `mutate` with `across` (from `dplyr` 1.0.0`or earlier versions with`mutate_at/mutate_all`)

```
library(dplyr)# 1.0.0
mydata %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), rank, .names = "{col}_rank"))
#  Train Test Train_rank Test_rank
#1  14.2 10.0          3         1
#2   2.2 11.2          1         2
#3  11.9 12.0          2         3
```

---

If we need to keep the row.names (which tidyverse omits), create a column with row names (`rownames_to_column`) and later change the column to rownames

```
library(tibble)
mydata %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  mutate(across(-rn, rank, .names = "{col}_rank")) %>%
  column_to_rownames('rn')
#         Train Test Train_rank Test_rank
#Method1  14.2 10.0          3         1
#Method2   2.2 11.2          1         2
#Method3  11.9 12.0          2         3
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
mydata[paste0(names(mydata), "_rank")] <- lapply(mydata, rank)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use data.table for that

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- data.table(Train = c(14.2, 2.2, 11.9), Test = c(10, 11.2, 12))
col_to_rank <- c('Train', 'Test')
mydata[, paste0('rank', col_to_rank) := lapply(.SD, rank), .SDcols = col_to_rank]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank` :

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% mutate(across(everything(), dense_rank, .names = '{col}_rank'))

#  Train Test Train_rank Test_rank
#1  14.2 10.0          3         1
#2   2.2 11.2          1         2
#3  11.9 12.0          2         3
```